# Regex Capture word between last dot and white space

Tags: python, string, extract

Trying to write re.search() that captures the word following the last dot and before the space that follows.

```
in1 = '<workalendar.america.canada.Quebec object at 0x0000021E5536B130>'
in2 = '<workalendar.america.canada.Canada object at 0x0000021E550F54F0>'
in3 = '<__main__.Zhraa object at 0x0000021E551FAF40>'
```

The desired output is

```
out1= 'Quebec'
out2= 'Canada'
out3= 'Zhraa'
```

Having a hard time with regex. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `in1.split()[0].split(".")[-1]` should work.

Comment: `split` is probably the best way to do this, but here's a regex: `p = '^.*\.(.*?) '`, 
`m = re.match(p, in1)`, `print(m[1])`